# How to switch the login button to logout when the user is authenticated successfully in bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

```
I developed a project using bootstrap and angular js. I want to change the login button to logout when a valid user logins successfully.
My Index.html code is given below:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>My Title</title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
                    <link rel="styleSheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.min.css" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

                    <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
                    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>-->

                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    <!--business table scripts -->
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
                    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

                    <!--css styles-->
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/business.css" />                 

            </head>
            <body ng-app="myapp">

                  <nav  class="navbar navbar-inverse" style= "margin-bottom:0px;height:90px;">                               
                        <div class="navbar-header">

                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color:#800000;
                                                                    font-weight: bold; 
                                                                    font-size:25px">MYApp                    
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li ><a style="color:#800000;" href="#">HOME</a></li>
                                <li ><a style="color:#800000;" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                                <li ><a style="color:#800000;" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">                  
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                  <li><a ui-sref="CATab.register">
                                            <b style="color:#800000; font-weight:bold;">Register</b>
                                      </a>
                                 </li>  



                                  <li>
                                      <a ui-sref="signin">
                                          <b style="color:#800000; font-weight:bold;">Login</b>                   
                                      </a>

                              </ul>   
                            </div>
                          </ul>
                        </div> 

              </nav>
              <div ui-view></div>
                  <!--<ui-view></ui-view>-->

             </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Code of my signin page:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="account-wall">
                 <h1 class="login-title">Sign in</h1>
                <form class="form-signin" ng-submit="check(uName,uPwd)" name="form" role="form">
                        <input  type="text" 
                                id="uName"  
                                class="form-control" 
                                placeholder="Username*" 
                                ng-model="uName"
                                required 
                                autofocus >
                        </input>
                        <br/>
                        <input  type="password"
                                id="uPwd" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                placeholder="Password*" 
                                ng-model="uPwd"
                                required >
                        </input>

                    <div        ng-show="errortxt" 
                                class="alert trmalert">
                                {{errortxt}}
                    </div>
                                <br/>  
                    <div class="form-actions">  
                        <button class="btn-block btn btn-danger" 
                                type="submit" >
                                Sign in
                        </button>
                    </div> 
                    <br/>
                    <a  ui-sref="forgotpwd" 
                        class="pull-right forgot-password ">Forgot password? 
                    </a>

                    <a  ui-sref="CATab.register" 
                        class="pull-left create-account">Create an account 
                    </a>
                    <br/>
                </form>
              </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

The code for the controller along with the function check(uName, uPwd) in app.js file is below:

```
//Signin Controllers starts here 
app.controller('signinCtrl',function($state,$scope,$location,$rootScope,$http)
{
    var fullName="";
    var errortxt = "";
    $scope.check = function(uName,uPwd)
        {
            $http(
                {
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/api/check",
                    data: { 
                            uName       : $scope.uName,
                            pwd         : $scope.uPwd
                          }
                })
            .success(function(result)
                {   
                    //$scope.fullName=result[0].fName; 
                    //alert(result[0].fName + $scope.fullName);
                     if (result.length == 1)
                     {
                      // result[0].fName +'' + result[0].lName;
                         $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
                         $location.path('/home');
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         $scope.errortxt = "Username or Password is incorrect";
                     }
                })
            .error(function(error)
                {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                alert ('failed'+ JSON.stri`enter code here`ngify(error));
            });
    }  
});
```

How to change the login button in the menu bar to logout when the user is authenticated successfully. Also once user press the logout button, then the logout button should change to login.

Screen shot for reference:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eBaa.png)

Please help to fix the issue.

Comment: This is a very common use case with lots of similar answers here on SO.

Anyways, your controller sets `loggedIn` on `$rootScope` but your html is waiting for `isLoggedIn`. Two different variables

Comment: On login you are redirecting to home and on logout you have to reset all variables and redirect to login page you can refer this link https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-authentication-angular-applications/